# awk do math between columns

Tags: awk

I'd like to filter the highest score from a second column out of a multiline record file. my approach is like:

```
awk ' BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"} {$2==max}  {print $2}' file
```

The sample looks like

```
104 9

110 8
111 5

116 6
117 7

130 11
131 16
132 15
133 10
134 6

146 8
147 8
148 8
```

but i got caught in the second line, because of the logic of the RS=""; FS="\n" . so my question, how how to split a multiline record field into subfields to do some min-max math?

the result should look like:

```
 5
 6
 6 
 7
 8
 8
 8
 8
 9
 10
 11
 15
 16
```

Comment: Please show your desired output for this sample input.

Comment: 5
 6
 6 
 7
 8
 8
 8
 8
 9
 10
 11
 15
 16 shoud it read

Answer (score 3):

You don't show any expected output so this is a guess but this might be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,a,/ /)
        max = ( (i==1) || (a[2] > max) ? a[2] : max )
    }
    print max
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
9
8
7
16
8
```

Comment: 5
 6
 6 
 7
 8
 8
 8
 8
 9
 10
 11
 15
 16

Comment: Are you seriously responding to your question 2 and a half years later??? Good luck!

Comment: I found accidently that discrepancy. But thanks your answer saved those days my week.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably not worry about messing with `RS` and `FS` for this one. Something along these lines might be easier:

```
awk 'BEGIN { max = -10000000 } NF == 2 { if ($2 > max) max = $2 } NF < 2 { print max; max = -10000000 }' file
```

If there's not an empty line at the end of your file, you might need to add a `END { print max }` clause to get the output from the last group...

Comment: @EdMorton True, but in the proffered sample input, everything appeared to be positive integers, so even `-1` would have sufficed, and I chose to keep the code parts a bit simpler. I did mention the possible need for `END...`, depending on whether there's a blank line at the end or not. Just another example of how there's generally several different approaches that can be taken...

Comment: Setting an arbitarily low number for max is bad coding practice.    `awk 'NF{max=max~/./||$2<max?max:$2}!NF&&max~/./{print max;max=""}END{if(max)print max}'`